# why their is little margin in between two red regions of the page shown?

Tags: html, css

As shown in image below their is little gap between two red regions..

[image]

I have set all the margins and paddings to zero but it is still giving that 4px(i think) margin in between.. I want to know why that is appearing there... 

two red regions are given floating to left and displayed as inline-block.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>learning...</title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="_body">
        <div id="_header">
            <img src="images/header_index.jpg"/>
            <br />
            <h3> this is just a view of uttrakhand from a camera come here and explore the whole beauty...</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="_navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="HtmlPage.html">Destinations</a></li>
                <li><a href="HtmlPage.html">Culture</a></li>
                <li><a href="HtmlPage.html">Adventure</a></li>
                <li><a href="HtmlPage.html">Hotels</a></li>
                <li><a href="HtmlPage.html">Wild Life</a></li>
                <li><a href="HtmlPage.html">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="HtmlPage.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="_left">
            this is left region of the page..
        </div>
        <div id="_content">
            this is content region of the page
        </div>
        <p id="background-viewer">..</p>
    </div>
    <pre>this is something written inside pre<a></a></pre>
    <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#_left , #_content , #_navigation > ul {
    display:inline-block;
}
#_body {
    width:1200px;
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#0000CC,#3999FF);
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:0px;
}
/*Here comes all the stylin gog header*/
#_header {

}
    #_header > img {
        width:1200px;
    }
    #_header > h3 {
        border-bottom:3px solid black;
        font-weight:normal;
        text-align:center;
        text-transform:capitalize;
        padding:10px;
    }

/*Here ends styling of header*/

/*here comes styling of navigatin bar*/
#_navigation {
    margin:20px 20px 10px 20px;

}
/*here remains 960px for navigation bar*/
    #_navigation > ul {
        list-style-type:none;
    }
    #_navigation ul > li {
        width:135px;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 15px 5px 0px;
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: 22px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,blue,aqua);
        border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
        border-top-left-radius:5px;
    }
        #_navigation ul > li:active {
            background:-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,blue,aqua);
        }
    #_navigation a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
        #_navigation a:visited {
            color:black;
        }
        #_navigation a:active {
            color:black;
        }
        #_navigation a:focus {
            color:black;
        }
/*here ends styling of _navigation*/

/*this part is for _left and _content*/
#_left {
    width:400px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:red;
    min-height:100px;
}
#_content {
    width:795px;
    background-color:red;
    min-height:100px;
}
/*here ends all the styling of mid region*/
```

Here is all of my code..
javascript file has nothing so i didn't put that here...

Comment: I am going to take a guess and say that your red containers are probably deeply embedded in sloppy CSS and HTML, which means that they are probably taking some CSS from other containers into account. If you could post some source code it would help.

Comment: how to write in editor..

Comment: @VVV You could post a jFiddle or use {} in the editor.

Comment: float:left on the #_content element works

Comment: I got the required effect. I forgot to put float:left in CSS :P
that's why this error occur

Answer (score 3):

Your divs are incorporated in a inline formating context and a whitespace is generated  by the new line in the html document

```
 <div id="_left">
    this is left region of the page..
</div>
<div id="_content">
    this is content region of the page
</div>
```

You may avoid that by putting together the closing and ending tag of those divs as so

```
<div id="_left">
    this is left region of the page..
</div><div id="_content">
    this is content region of the page
</div>
```

Comment: See also:  http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

A good idea is to use google chrome or firefox to inspect the elements you want to understand more. Just right click on your red block, inspect element. This then shows you the css applicable to the elements, including any inherited from other elements. You can live test alternatives by either editing the css code in the inspector or by editing the style sheet also presented by the inspector.

Ok, try

```
#_content {
 float:left
}
```

here's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cfgXX/